# Is it possible to test PayPal's Payflow Gateway using live card info?

Tags: paypal, payflowpro

I'm pretty sure I'm using what is currently branded as "Payflow Gateway" where I get a secure token and redirect the customer to payflowlink.paypal.com.  I created a test account and can successfully send a customer to PayPal (creating the token with MODE=TEST and passing TRXTYPE=A), process fake card number 4111-1111-1111-1111, and return to my site.  But I want to test the AVS fraud filter and it seems like the only way I can do that is to enter a live card number, namely my own.  However, when I enter all the information exactly correct, including CVC and my address info, the transaction is always rejected with RESULT=12.

Does anyone know if real card numbers can be sent in test mode?  If not, my next stackoverflow question will be "How can I test the Payflow Gateway AVS fraud filter".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Payflow gateway will always decline a live credit card that is entered in test mode. Here is the documenation. Its under 'Real credit card numbers on Test Servers'.
https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1234&actp=LIST

So to answer "How can I test the Payflow Gateway AVS fraud filter":
https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_payflowpro_fps_guide.pdf
Go to page 18.

Comment: FYI, the PDF link brings up a document that says the documentation has moved to a web page, with an unclickable link.  Here is the link: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/fraud-protection/